# Airflow how to import python script?

Tags: python, import, airflow

I have a file `survey_monkey.py` and a directory `surveymonkey` in the dag folder. There is a python script named `surveys.py` in the directory `surveymonkey`.

```
from surveys import Surveys

# defining DAG arguments

# You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
default_args = {
    'owner': 'survey_monkey'，
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email': ['xxxx@xxxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
```

This givs me an error saying

```
Broken DAG: [/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools/survey_monkey.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools/survey_monkey.py", line 11, in <module>
    from surveys import Surveys
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surveys'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The import path should be relative to dags folder.
Since `surveys` stays inside `surveymonkey` which is in dag folder.

Replace following line:

```
from surveys import Surveys
```

with:

```
from surveymonkey.surveys import Surveys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. add your modules to one of the folders that Airflow automatically adds to PYTHONPATH
2. add extra folders where you keep your code to PYTHONPATH
3. package your code into a Python package and install it together with Airflow.

Airflow has [Modules Management](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html) documentation that explains it thoroughly.

In your case the module you wish to import exist in the DAG folder (Which already exist in PYTHONPATH) so you can simply import it with a path relative to your DAG folder. The following import should work:

```
from survey_tools.survey_monkey.surveys import Surveys
```